# IntelliJ for scala worksheet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I got the following error from time to time when working with scala worksheet in IntelliJ, it happens from time to time, happens at one moment but gone in next moment. Is it something wrong with my environment  setup or it is an issue in IntelliJ?

```
Internal error: week6.A$A9
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ClientEventProcessor.process(ClientEventProcessor.scala:22)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.handle(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:47)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.handle(RemoteServerRunner.scala:14)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:30)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.send(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.send(RemoteServerRunner.scala:14)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcVI$sp(RemoteServerRunner.scala:33)
scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:166)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner$$anon$1.run(RemoteServerRunner.scala:30)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.server.RemoteServerConnector.compileAndRun(RemoteServerConnector.scala:85)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.processor.WorksheetCompiler$$anon$1.run(WorksheetCompiler.scala:76)
com.intellij.compiler.progress.CompilerTask.run(CompilerTask.java:196)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:710)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:179)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:568)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:519)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:128)
com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:309)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you have code in your worksheet?